# find two matches with exactly `n` lines in between

Tags: linux, awk, grep

In my Linux terminal, I need to find the number of such occurrences, where `pattern 1` and `pattern 2` appears in two lines which are exactly `n` lines apart, with the additional requirement that `pattern 3` cannot appear in any of these `n` lines.
For example, if I have a text file

```
...
a
* pat1 **
b
c
** pat2 ****
* pat1 **
b
** pat2 ****
*******pat1**
efda
*pat3****
**pat2********
...
```

when `n=2` and `pattern 1` is `pat1`, `pattern 2` is `pat2`, and `pattern 3` is `pat3`, then there are only 1 occurrence.

How to do this conveniently in utility tools like `awk`, `grep` (or its sisters) etc. I know how to use python or perl to do this, but just wonder if these utility tools can do the same.

Thank you.

This is what I tried after reading @Barmar's answer

```
awk -v n=2 '/pat1/ { first = NR } 
           !/pat3/ 
            /pat2/ && first && NR - first == n { count++ } END {print count}'
```

But I still did not get it correctly. I need to do this for four scenarios:

- `pat1` and `pat3` are the same.
- `pat2` and `pat3` are the same.
- all of these three patterns are the same.
- no two of these are the same.

Comment: Can the patterns arbitrarily overlap? In particular, could you have, e.g. `pat1/pat1/pat2`?

Comment: @QiangLi Whats your expected output from above sample data, it will be easier to understand your requirement that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v n=2 '/pat1/ { first = NR }
            /pat2/ && first && NR - first == n { count++ }
            END {print count}'
```

Here's the code with the additional `pat3` requirement:

```
awk -v n=2 '/pat3/ && first { pat3 = 1; first = 0 }
            /pat1/ && !pat3 { first = NR }
            /pat2/ && first && NR - first == n { count++; first = 0 }
            END {print count}'
```

I think this will work with all the combinations of patterns being the same, but I haven't tested it. What makes this trick when patterns can be the same is that a line matching one test in the script doesn't prevent it from being put through remaining tests. So the script has to reset the state variables `pat3` and `first` to avoid treating the same line as both a `pat1` and `pat3` match.

In your attempt, the line

```
!/pat3/
```

doesn't do anything. First of all, it's not syntactically correct -- every test needs to be followed by a statement or block saying what to do when it's matched. Second, even if you'd put an empty block after it, that just means "if the current line doesn't match pat3, don't do anything". It doesn't have any effect on the behavior of the other pattern matches in the script.

I think you need to find an awk tutorial to learn the basic operation model of awk. I'm not going to try to teach you it here, this is not a tutoring site.

Comment: +1. Thank you so much Barmar! I am really that I missed one important requirement. Would you please take another look?

Comment: Maybe it's time for you to start programming for yourself, that's how you learn. From my code, it should be pretty easy to add the third check.

Comment: awk -v n=2 '/pat1/ { first = NR } !/pat3/
            /pat2/ && first && NR - first == n { count++ }
            END {print count}'
I am having trouble when `pattern 1` and `pattern 3` can be the same, meaning pattern1 does not appear again between `pattern 1` and `pattern 2`

Comment: I can't read your code in the comments, you should post it in the question. It also gets trickier when some of the patterns can be the same. You need to set variables to keep track of the state.

Answer (score 1):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -ne '/pat1/{N;N;/\([^\n]*\n\)\{2\}.*pat2/{/pat3/!p}}' input
```

Some explanation:

```
if (pat1 matches) {                     #  /pat1/{
     read and append 2 lines            #  N;N;
     if (pat2 matches after 2 '\n's) {  #  /\([^\n]*\n\)\{2\}.*pat2/ {
          if (pat3 does not match) {    #  /pat3/!
             print                      #  p
          }                             
      }                                 #  }
 }                                      #  }
```

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot! Could you give some detailed explanation about these commands please?

Comment: added some details, hope this helps